# How to get ONLY the name of second highest salaried person

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How to get ONLY the name of second (or nth) highest salaried person?

This is the query I have tried but this gives me only the name of highest salary paid:

```
SELECT emp_name FROM emp ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, stack overflow won't provide code for you, they will fix what you've tried but not give you code

Comment: SELECT emp_name FROM emp ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1;                 this is the query I have tried bt this gives me nly name of highest salary paid

Comment: You want to do 2 limits, one in your initial select query and one after, try this: `SELECT emp_name,salary FROM ( SELECT emp_name,salary FROM emp ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 2 ) ORDER BY salary ASC LIMIT 1;`

Comment: SELECT emp_name FROM emp ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1,1

Comment: I tried your code @ZachRoss-Clyne but it is throwing an error "ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: Hey @davidstrachan your code worked!!! Thanks alot guys thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that the best solution, but here is an example how you could do it:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT customerName, length(customerName), @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank 
FROM zenyatech.customer, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r 
ORDER BY length(customerName) 
) X WHERE rank = 2
```

You create a rank column first, and then use a query around that query and get only rank = 2 or N.

(The example is a little different, you would need to apply that to your table/database scenario)

Comment: No #bdifferent its not working for name of second highest person

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
SELECT name FROM employees ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1,1
```